# how to set p, h1, ul on same height in flexbox/grid

Tags: html, css, alignment, height

I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/yedovc7w/

```css
body,
p,
h1,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
}

.left,
.right {
  border: 2px black solid;
  height: 400px;
}

.right {
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <p>xLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium sit deserunt nisi. Qui provident sit minima eius. Voluptatem ea perspiciatis obcaecati iure. Sequi adipisci rerum laudantium voluptates id quod minus.Schlüsselqualifikationen</p>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <ul>
      <li class="nav-desktop" role="presentation">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h1>Hi ich bin hier</h1>
    <p>xLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium sit deserunt nisi. Qui provident sit minima eius. Voluptatem ea perspiciatis obcaecati iure. Sequi adipisci rerum laudantium voluptates id quod minus.Schlüsselqualifikationen</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that the text as well as the h1 and the heading start at the **same** "height". With same height I mean, that all start at the top of the div.

How can I achieve this?

Also the dot of the ul element (I want to have this "dot"!) moves to the wrong box. I want this to be in the box where the li is.

[I want to align the items at the red line or in other words - same line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJMMW.png)

Comment: list-style-position: inside should get the disc into the column. I don't understand what alignment you want. Are each of the two 'xLorem...' to be at the same level (i.e. a gap at the top of the first?) And what of the ul item?

Comment: thanks, that works. With same height i mean that the h1, the p, and the li are at the same height or in other words on one line

Comment: Ah, so whatever the font-sizes (especially of the h1 which is likely to be the largesst) they all appear on one line - the characters' baselines to be level.

Comment: Can you change the HTML structure?

Comment: yes structure can be changed. 
Is there no way to align them not based on the "middleline" of the characters but by the upper left edge?

Comment: They are aligned on the 'upper left edge' now. I think I need a picture to understand what you want aligned with what!

Comment: sure! I want the texts align agains the (in this case) red line or in other words the same line. Here is a scrrenshot of what i mean: https://i.ibb.co/Gp49Rr3/Unbenannt.png

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body, p, h1, ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .content {
            display: flex;
            /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
        }

        .left, .right {
            border: 2px black solid;
            height: 400px;
        }

        .right {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .middle {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .left {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left"></br></br>
            <p>xLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium sit deserunt nisi. Qui provident sit minima eius. Voluptatem ea perspiciatis obcaecati iure. Sequi adipisci rerum laudantium voluptates id quod minus.Schlüsselqualifikationen</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middle"></br></br>
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-desktop" role="presentation" style="margin-left: 20px">
                  <a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <h1>Hi ich bin hier</h1>
            <p>xLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium sit deserunt nisi. Qui provident sit minima eius. Voluptatem ea perspiciatis obcaecati iure. Sequi adipisci rerum laudantium voluptates id quod minus.Schlüsselqualifikationen</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All I added was double `br` in the start of the middle and left divs, as well as a margin-left of 20px for the link in the middle section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the double <br> doesn't exactly bring the elements on the same height! Is you remove the middle div you can see this.